# ng-message-exp shows all messages

Tags: angularjs, ng-messages

When I use `ng-message`, it works as intended. However, when I try to use `ng-message-exp`, it shows all messages at once. Can someone confirm if it is a bug?

Please find the [plnk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/O0vJiRrvDx4M3s9xSWCF?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.18/docs/api/ngMessages), `ngMessageExp` directive is not defined in **Angularjs 1.3**. You should upgrade to **1.4**